# Keyboard not working in some applications after installation of Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: keyboard, 14.10

I just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.10. I can use my keyboard normally in most windows (i.e. browser window to type this question) however the keyboard doesn't work at all in certain functions like for example typing something on the 'search documents and folders by name' field of a window or when I try to rename a document on the desktop.

Nothing happens, it looks like the keyboard input is dead at that point.

If I switch to another window, like back to a browser or even type within a document, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong? I know it might be something silly... thanks for answering!

Comment: FYI I have noticed that after rebooting, the problem goes away temporarily. Everything is back to normal and I can type stuff on the fields described above, but after Ubuntu is running for a while, let's say 30-45 minutes it starts happening again...it's so frustrating! not sure if this is a bug or not but I never had this problem with 14.04 and I was running it on the same laptop for a while...thanks!

Comment: ...and the LAST update. Ubuntu pushed an update yesterday 10/29 not sure which one it was but it fixed the issue. I was having this problem since I installed 14.10 but after the update from yesterday everything works fine, back to normal...no keyboard issues :-)